# How to make PM2 reload a node_modules sub-folder

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have a NodeJS app `my-project`, that has a module `my-module` as a dependency. Currently, whenever I make changes to `my-module`, I have to `ctrl + C` to quit PM2, and type `pm2 start ...` to start up `my-project` again.

This is my `pm2` config file. As you can see, watch is already enabled; However, unless I quit and restart, the changes are not reflected.

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "script": "dist/index.js",
  "watch": ["src", "../my-module/src"],
  "ignore_watch": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "env": {
    "NODE_ENV": "development",
    "PORT": 8000
  },
  "watch_options": {
    "followSymlinks": false
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make it so that if I make changes to `my-modules`, they are reflected by the watch option, rather than manual restart?